# expected identifier in c language

Tags: c, compiler-errors, cs50

Here Iam trying to write program but using **NOT(!)** creating error:

```
int find_min(void)
{
    mini=voter_count;
    for(int i=0;  i>candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes<mini) && !(candidates[i].eliminated){
            mini = candidates[i].votes;
        }
    }
    return mini;
}
```

when program was to compile it was making error as:

```
runoff.c:187:42: error: expected identifier
        if (candidates[i].votes<mini) && !(candidates[i].eliminated)){
                                         ^**
```

but i matched the curly braces and when I remove **!** symbol it will get compiled with no error.

Comment: Try `(candidates[i].votes<mini  && !candidates[i].eliminated)`  Removed a `)` and `(`.

Comment: Omkar, Review use of `>` in `i>candidate_count`.  Sure you want "greater than"?

Comment: In C the `if` syntax requires the condition to be fully parenthesized.

Comment: thank you it worked and I should use < symbol

Answer (score 1):

In C, the expression of an `if` statement needs to be in parens:

```
if (expression) 
{
    /* do work */
}
```

However, what you wrote is:

```
if (expr1) && !(expr2)
{
    /* do work */
}
```

Fix this by putting your entire expression in parens:

```
if ( (expr1) && !(expr2) )     /* <== Note the outer-parens */
{
    /* do work */
}
```

I know that some other languages, most notably Python, do *not* require the expression be inside parens.  But in C, it is very important.